# IIS 7.5 http-redirect inherits from default web site?

Tags: asp.net, iis, redirect, iis-7.5, http-redirect

Default web site is set to redirect to a startup-application:

`http://foo.bar.com` becomes `https://foo.bar.com/startapplication` and it works fine.

However, i have another application on the web server and it should redirect to itself if called with http.

So for example this:

```
http://foo.bar.com/application
```

Should become this:

```
https://foo.bar.com/application
```

BUT

it becomes:

```
https://foo.bar.com/startapplication/application
```

It seems that the web server ( iis 7.5 ) inherits the http redirect in some kind of way from the default web site.

Is this standard behaviour or am i missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) extension (if you haven't already) and configure an inbound rule as seen in the screenshots. Don't forget to disable your redirects.

[image: Rewrite rule http to https - part 1]
[image: Rewrite rule http to https - part 2]